# Combinatorial explanation for an identity of the partition function

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, integer-partitions

One can employ elementary methods to demonstrate that $p(n) \leq p(n-1) + p(n-2)$ for $n \geq 2$. Recently, I showed that if certain restrictions are imposed on the partitions, the inequality becomes an equality.

\begin{equation}
    \notag
    \begin{aligned}
        &\ \ \ \ p(n\mid{\mathrm{parts}}\not\equiv{12,15,27}\ (\mathrm{mod}\ {27})) \\
        &=p(n-1\mid{\mathrm{parts}}\not\equiv{6,21,27}\ (\mathrm{mod}\ {27}))) \\
        &+p(n-2\mid{\mathrm{parts}}\not\equiv{3,24,27}\ (\mathrm{mod}\ {27}))). \\
    \end{aligned}
\end{equation}

I proved this identity using some $q$-series theory (https://arxiv.org/abs/2308.06289). Is it possible to find a combinatorial explanation for it?

Comment: $27$ seems a little bit arbitrary. Did you obtain similar identities with different numbers?

Comment: @Fikilis No. Not to my knowledge.

Comment: A vague idea: Modify the bijective proof of Euler's recurrence $$p(n) = p(n-1) + p(n-2) - p(n-5) - p(n-7) + \cdots$$ by Bressoud and Zeilberger (*American Mathematical Monthly* 92 (1985) pp54-55) and show that the truncation $a(n) = b(n-1) + c(n-2)$ for your restricted partitions has nothing left over.